# jpa specification query method

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, specifications

We are using the Spring Data JPA for database access. Our repositories contain basic query methods. What we want to do now is to use the Specification-Interface (criteria API) *combined* with complex query methods (like `findByName(Specification spec)`). The problem is that these two ways block each other out (since there are two `where` queries now). Is there any way to do this, like telling JPA to combine the two `where` parts with `AND`? The reason we want to do this is because some parts of the `where` query are essential for every query. They should be defined in the name of the query method. The Specification only should contain individual criterias for individual use-cases.
Or is there any other way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not supported. Please feel free to raise a JIRA issue if you think this would be a worthwhile enhancement.

Comment: Talk about a credible source.